# Spock: console output to log4j / graylog

Tags: log4j, spock

We are using the Spock framework for automated testing. The output of the tests (e.g. assert failures etc.) is sent to the console.

I also want to send the output to log4j / graylog, but I just do n't understand how to do that or if that is even possible.

Is Spock using log4j? Or is it sending the output directly to stdout / stderr?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a logback configuration you need to add it before you can use logging feature. To setup logback please refer to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/logback-configuration-using-groovy).